# How can I connect my java phone's internet to my pc?

Tags: networking

Itried a lot to connect my java mobile for sharing internet in my phone. But I don't know how to make the connection true. How can I connect my mobile phone(java) as a mobile broadband to share internet to my computer?

Comment: the model phone you have?

Comment: The set I have is Samsung Rex-60

Comment: Solved with sharing internet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to search on google: [active tethering and router wifi](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=active%20tethering%20and%20router%20wifi) and so you will have istructions .
Before you can see if you model support you option on this [site](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812516?hl=en-GB)

Update:
see this [guide official of samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportOwnersHowToGuidePopup.do?howto_guide_seq=5645&prd_ia_cd=N0000003&map_seq=34471) because you model can share internet

Answer (score 0):

This is really going to depend on the phone. In some instances you are going to have to install a program in the google market place to download a tethering app. In other cases, tethering is already included in the phone. If I go to settings, more networks, and go to tethering and mobile hotspot it will give the option for me to tether my phone using usb, or wifi. This is also going to depend on your service provider because some service providers lock down tethering unless you have a plan aka MetroPCS. In some cases, like one of my older phones you can get around this using one of the tethering apps, but in other cases the phone is really locked down and the only options are to either pay or to root your phone using something like multirom.

Comment: Can you name some java tethering apps if any?